# Простой http сервер на nodejs: response time 1 милисекунда это много?

Tags: node.js, производительность, fastify

господа.
Написал простейший http сервер на ноде (v15.11) на fastify (v3.20.2) (как одной из самых производительных библиотек на ноде для этих целей). И результаты меня несколько удручают:

- при отправке 1 запроса время ответа +/- 1 милисекунда
- при отправке 10 одновременных запросов среднее время ответа = 5,6 милисекунд

```
Min time: 4 msec 5 µsec 800 nsec
Max time: 5 msec 913 µsec 200 nsec
Avg time: 5 msec 560 µsec 150 nsec
```

- при отправке 100 одновременных запросов среднее время ответа = 41 милисекунд

```
Min time: 21 msec 212 µsec 300 nsec
Max time: 41 msec 570 µsec 300 nsec
Avg time: 40 msec 918 µsec 113 nsec
```

Как мне кажется для сервера который ничего не делает это ОЧЕНЬ большие тайминги. Может я что-то не правильно делаю? Какие будут мысли на этот счет?

Исходный код:

```js
// server.js
const server = require('fastify')({ keepAliveTimeout: 20000 })

server.get('/ping', async (req, res) => {
  res.code(200).send('')
})

server.listen(3000)
```

```js
// benchmark.js
const http = require('http')

const ITER = 100
const agent = new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true, maxFreeSockets: 500 })
const { hrtime } = process

console.log('Starting benchmark...')
const hrStart = hrtime.bigint()

makeRequest(0)             // make 1 request for a handshake
  .then(() => start(ITER)) // start benchmark
  .then(results => {       // display benchmark results
    console.log(`Benchmark finished in ${stringify(hrtime.bigint() - hrStart)}`)
    const min = results.reduce((res, v) => Math.min(res, v), Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
    const max = results.reduce((res, v) => Math.max(res, v), 0)
    const total = results.reduce((res, v) => res + v, 0)
    console.log(`Min time: ${stringify(min)}`)
    console.log(`Max time: ${stringify(max)}`)
    console.log(`Avg time: ${stringify(Math.round(total / ITER))}`)
  })


async function start(iterCount) {
  const results = new Array(ITER) // an array of elapsed time for each request
  for(let nIter = 0; nIter < iterCount; ++nIter) {
    results[nIter] = makeRequest(nIter).then(({ iter, elapsed }) => results[iter] = elapsed)
  }
  return Promise.all(results).then(() => results)
}

function makeRequest(iter) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const start = hrtime.bigint()
    http.get('http://localhost:3000/ping', { agent } , res => {
      res.resume().on('end', () => resolve({ iter, elapsed: Number(hrtime.bigint() - start) }))
    })
  })
}

function stringify(time) {
  time = Number(time)
  if(Number.isNaN(time)) {
    throw new Error(`time is not a number`)
  }
  const nsec = time % 1000
  time = (time - nsec) / 1000
  const mcsec = time % 1000
  time = (time - mcsec) / 1000
  const msec = time
  return `${msec} msec ${mcsec} µsec ${nsec} nsec`
}
```

Comment: Вы всё очень хорошо написали, но есть одно большое «НО». На самом деле вы проверили не производительность сервера, а «производительность» клиента (бенчмарка).

Comment: Вполне возможно с Вами соглашусь, у меня тоже есть подозрения, что проблема в самом клиенте. Но как тогда проверить сервер? Писать клиент на С++?

Comment: Взять любой готовый. [apache benchmark](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html), например

Comment: На моём ноутбуке команда `ab -n 100000 -c 1000 localhost:3000/ping` выдаёт `Time per request:       0.079 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)`

https://pastebin.com/wVZPmWdY

Comment: Спасибо за отличные комментарии. А на каком железе Вы проводили тестирование? У меня на i7 `Time per request:  0.318 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)`, хотелось бы понять почему такая большая разница в результатах.

Comment: `Quad-Core Intel® Core™ i7-8650U CPU @ 1.90GHz` Но вообще это просто пузомерка. Ни в одном реальном приложении вы не упрётесь в производительность сетевого/http стека ноды.

Comment: Я отлично понимаю информативность данного исследования. Меня интересовали 2 вещи: граничные возможности самого веб-сервиса на 1 кластере ноды (например если данные вытягиваются из memory cache, а не БД) и сопоставимость `fastify` и`express`

Comment: Ну тогда я бы ещё сравнил с «голой» нодой без фреймворков.

Comment: Если не видели, посмотрите сравнения производительности разных фреймворков и языков в разных сценариях https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/ . Там fastify, кстати, не самый быстрый для js.

Answer (score 0):

Александр,

позвольте для начала Вас похвалить за отлично проделанную работу!

Вы не только написали сервер, померили, задумались о скорости, задали вопрос - вы еще, фактически, дали отвечающим свою методику измерений.

Теперь - по сути: ну вроде 1 мс (то есть одна тысячная доля секунды) на запрос - это неплохо. Ведь там огромные накладные расходы: открывается tcp коннекшн, происходит начальный хэндшейкинг, потом начинается запихивание в этот коннекшн http заголовков с одной стороны и их обработка на другой стороне. Целое дело!

При этом нода сторит "машину состояний" для того, чтобы по завершеню получения запроса запустить тот код, который будет отвечать. а нода - это интерпретатор, хоть и очень быстрый.

А вообще вопрос интересный. Если он останется открытым и актуальным - я могу попробовать через день-два померить время чисто открытия tcp коннекшна и время такого же сервера, который хостит статику, но написанного на C++.

Еще, говорят, в Golang довольно популярны пузомерки на самый быстрый http ответ. Хотя, если нужна именно скорость - то, может, просто не использовать http? Например, многие биржевые протоколы основаны чисто на udp пакетах.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Но мне кажется, что 1 мсек это очень много. Начальный хендшейк не попадает в бенчмарк так как 1й запрос на сервер специально вынесен за рамки измерения (строка №8 в benchmark.js `makeRequest(0)`). Т.е. по сути бенчмарк одного запроса осуществляется с открытым сокетным соединением (благодаря keep alive). Особо накладных расходов тоже не вижу: "запихивание заголовков" и формирования запроса  это отправка в сеть 112 байтов данных. На С++ сервере это по-идеи занимает несколько десятков микросекунд. Вот что выдал Wireshark

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWQgn.png

Comment: самое интересное, что согласно скриншоту Wireshark (в комментарии выше), то с момента ухода данных в сеть (запрос №9) и получением ответа прошло 185!!! микросекунд. Т.е. сервер за это время успел принять запрос, распарсить его и дать ответ (что абсолютно не сложнее формирование самого запроса). Куда же подевались остальные 800 микросекунд?

Comment: Очень ценные замечания сделал Alexey Ten. А я подумал, что простым - и готовым - эталоном скорости может быть измерение скорости ответа nginx'а, раздающего статику. Если будет время - попробую в течение дня померить...

Comment: > Куда же подевались остальные 800 микросекунд? - а я, кажется, догадываюсь. Я почти уверен, что node испольузет epoll с таймером - то есть, фактически, опрашивает открытые соекеты раз в какое то - очень маленькое - время. То есть, упор делается не на мгновенность ответа, а на возможность получить очередные порции данных сразу из кучи сокетов, поставить всё жэто в очередь и ответитьв пределах одного треда - задержка получается заметной, но "passthrough" - средняя скорость "прохождения запросов" через сервер - высокой. Но это - гипотеза, может, есть кто то поумнее меня?

Comment: интересное предположение, его бы еще проверить..